# php Comparing date if date format in database is like this (02/02/2014)

Tags: php, mysql

I wants to fetch some data from my database table. my mysql query is bellow.

```
$sql = 'SELECT *
FROM advertisments 
WHERE ad_type = "Jobs"
AND last_date <= "' . $todays_date .'" ';
```

let me know how it works if  in table   last_date   format is  like this  (day/month/year  01/01/2014)
and  $today_date = 02/02/2014 .   in my case it is not working. let me know how can i compare this situation.

Comment: What datatype are you using in your database for the last_date column? If it isn't one of the built-in date/time datatypes (Date, DateTime or Timestamp), then why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's not working I'd hazard a guess that your `last_date` column is not a date/time type in your database and so the database software is probably just performing a string comparison.

Set the last_date type to `DATE` and then `last_date <= "' . $todays_date .'" ';` should work just fine if $todays_date is in the correct format.

Edit: I believe MySQL date uses the format `Y-m-d`

Comment: let me check your suggestion.

Comment: I have set the datatype of  last_date to DATE, But format for this by default is  Year-month-date    does it possible date-month-year   if yes then how please tell me.

Comment: Just change the format of your `$today_date = "2014-02-02"`, if you're getting `02/02/2014` from somewhere it should be relatively easy to convert between the formats.

Answer (score 0):

Just by googling about how to convert `time` into `datetime` and then compare `datetime` instead of only `time`.